# COW vs ROW snapshot Technologies

Tags: storage, snapshot, copy-on-write, read-committed-snapshot

While Im reading about the Snapshot Technology...I found Copy-On-Write (COW) and Redirect-On-Write (ROW) a quite Confusing to Understand the actual Operations they are Committing to...Will Somebody Please Explain me How They are Working Actually...

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

COW copies the old value to a separate area in the snapshot before writing the new data in the original place. This means a file will stay contiguous. ROW writes to a new area, and keeps the original data in the snapshot. This saves the copy, so it is faster, but makes files noncontiguous.